# converting iptables to ip6tables

Tags: linux, bash, firewall, iptables

I have the following **iptables** commands in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
 sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT
 sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --gid-owner internet -j ACCEPT
```

And it works fine. The problem is I would like to include the equivalent **ip6tables** commands in the bash script, and I'm not sure what changes would have to be made.

So for instance, if I change all the instances of the word **iptables** to **ip6tables** I would get the following:

```
 sudo ip6tables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT
 sudo ip6tables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT
 sudo ip6tables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
 sudo ip6tables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --gid-owner internet -j ACCEPT
```

But then I noticed that the ip addresses being used (**192.168.0.1/24 and 127.0.0.1**) are in the **IPv4** format, and I assume they have to be made in some sort of an equivalent for **IPv6**?

**Question:** What would be the equivalent of the pervious 2 IP Addresses for **IPv6**? What other changes would the **IPv6** script need in order to work properly?

Comment: for localhost (127.0.0.1) you want `::1`, but there is no direct equivalent for RFC 1918 addresses in IPv6, the required address depends on what the second rule is trying to achieve and the network configuration.

Comment: Hi @user1937198 ! The previous script is for a personal computer to have full control over what programs are using an internet connection, so that the amount of consumption can be controled (and not have random programs downloading stuff). By creating a group called "internet" `sudo groupadd internet`, and then after running the previous script, by running `sudo -g internet -s` inside a terminal, that terminal would be able to call a browser, or another program which uses the internet, and the connection would be limited to that program.

Answer (score -1):

get rid of those IPs and match on the interface.

`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT`